# How do i echo all images in an array from database path

Tags: php

please can some one help me out, i am new with php I am trying to display images stored in a folder called uploads, all the images path are stored in one field I called ,file
**this is form code**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <table width="800" align="center">
<tr>
<td> <h1>Insert new post</h1> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Post Title:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="post_title" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Post Image:</td>
<td> 
<input name="file[]" type="file" id="file"/>
<input type="button" id="add_more" class="upload" value="Add More Files"/> 
</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Post Content:</td>
<td><textarea name="post_content" rows="16" cols="30"> </textarea></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
```

```
 <?php 

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 $errors= array();

 $j = 0;     
$target_path = "uploads/";     

 for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {

 $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png" , "gif");      

 $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));  

$file_extension = end($ext); // Store extensions in the variable.

 $target_path = $target_path. md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1] ;   

 $j = $j + 1;    

 if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000)    
 && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
 $file_name_all.=$target_path."*";
            $filepath = rtrim($file_name_all.''); 

       $post_title = $_POST['post_title'];
 $post_content = $_POST['post_content'];

if($post_title=='') {

 echo "<script>alert('please fill all feilds') </script>" ;
        exit();
        }   

    else {   

     $insert_posts = "insert into posts              (post_title,file,post_content) values          ( '$post_title','$target_path','$post_content')";

      $run_posts = mysql_query($insert_posts);

    echo"<script>alert('post has been published!')</script>";
    } 
} 
    ?>
```

**and here is the preview code**

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET['cat'])) {

    $get_posts = "select *from posts limit 0,5 ";
    $run_posts = mysql_query($get_posts);
    while ($row_posts = mysql_fetch_array($run_posts))

    $post_id = $row_posts['post_id'];               
    $post_title = $row_posts['post_title'];
    $file =   $row_posts['file'];
    $post_content =substr($row_posts['post_content'],0,200);

    echo"
    <li>
<h3><a id=1title' href='details.php?post=$post_id'>$post_title</a></h3>
<img  src='uploads/$file' width='250' height='150'/>    
</p>    
$post_content 
<div >

 </div><br/> 

</li>       
    ";
 ?>
```

and below is the path of two images i uploaded to the database , my aim is to display these images

uploads/c1d225856af139c794b5358e61e99cd3.jpg1935ecdda8ed0c5602286a5398959931.jpg

Comment: Can you reduce the amount of code, I'm not sure in which script you are trying to echo. Also `limit $page1,5` seems incorrect.

Comment: Waaayyyy too much code. You need to do a better job of narrowing this down to the actual broken code. Otherwise this is just a "fix my code for me" question.

Comment: Here's some fixes on the preview code : [Little fixed](http://pastebin.com/WCVuteXs). And about your query, you can't put $page1 there because this variable is undefined, i couldn't find it in all your code. And to the limit thing, I think you should just put how much rows do you have to get from it, so just you put 5 after 'limit' , I didn't change that on my pastebin, so you should do it on your own